# "TypeError: expected string or buffer" when using tika to parse documents in Python

Tags: python, parsing, apache-tika, named-entity-recognition, named-entity-extraction

I am trying to parse some documents (as listed in filetypes) using Apache Tika. This is my code in Python.

```
auth = urllib2.HTTPPasswordMgrWithDefaultRealm()
auth.add_password(None, url, user, password)
urllib2.install_opener(urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPBasicAuthHandler(auth)))

outpage = urllib2.urlopen(url)
data = json.loads(outpage.read().decode('utf-8'))
dictitems = data.values()
flattened_list = [y for x in dictitems for y in x]

filetypes = [".pdf", ".doc", ".docx", ".txt"]

def tikiparse(fi):
    for i in filetypes:
        if fi.endswith(i):
            text = parser.from_file(fi, "http://localhost:9998/")
            extractedcontent = text["content"]

            chunked = ne_chunk(pos_tag(word_tokenize(extractedcontent)))
            current_chunk = []
            cont_chunk = []

            for j in chunked:
                if type(j) == Tree:
                    current_chunk.append(" ".join([token for token, pos in j.leaves()]))
                elif current_chunk:
                    named_entity = " ".join(current_chunk)
                    if named_entity not in cont_chunk:
                        cont_chunk.append(named_entity)
                        current_chunk = []
                else:
                    continue
            return cont_chunk
```

The loop runs perfectly for a while and parses some documents to extract named entities. And abruptly, I get the following error. What is going wrong with the code?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Kalapala/PycharmProjects/Attachments/DownloadFiles.py", line 74, in <module>
    tikiparse(f)
  File "C:/Users/Kalapala/PycharmProjects/Attachments/DownloadFiles.py", line 57, in tikiparse
    chunked = ne_chunk(pos_tag(word_tokenize(extractedcontent)))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk\tokenize\__init__.py", line 130, in word_tokenize
    sentences = [text] if preserve_line else sent_tokenize(text, language)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk\tokenize\__init__.py", line 97, in sent_tokenize
    return tokenizer.tokenize(text)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk\tokenize\punkt.py", line 1235, in tokenize
    return list(self.sentences_from_text(text, realign_boundaries))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk\tokenize\punkt.py", line 1283, in sentences_from_text
    return [text[s:e] for s, e in self.span_tokenize(text, realign_boundaries)]
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk\tokenize\punkt.py", line 1274, in span_tokenize
    return [(sl.start, sl.stop) for sl in slices]
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk\tokenize\punkt.py", line 1314, in _realign_boundaries
    for sl1, sl2 in _pair_iter(slices):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk\tokenize\punkt.py", line 312, in _pair_iter
    prev = next(it)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk\tokenize\punkt.py", line 1287, in _slices_from_text
    for match in self._lang_vars.period_context_re().finditer(text):
TypeError: expected string or buffer

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: can you post the code related to `parser.from_file()`?

Comment: It is the 12th line of the sample I posted. And these are the lines that follow the function:  for f in os.listdir('<folder>'):
    tikiparse(f)

Comment: have you checked the type of `extractedcontent`? It is supposed to be a string

Comment: The type is "unicode". When I try to convert it to str, I get a UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xc2 in position 9: unexpected end of data

Comment: now you know where the error come from, see details in my post, please

Answer (score 1):

The issue you have is `word_tokenise()` expects a string, but you pass other type into the method. You have to make sure your `extractedcontent` is string type.

Based on your `UnicodeDecodeError`comment, the values of dictionary `text` contain some characters which cannot be encoded/decode, you can call encode('utf-8').strip() on the value, for instance `extractedcontent.encode('utf-8').strip()` to resolve it.

Hope it helps.

Comment: And now this is the error I get: UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc2 in position 9: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: There's a typo it should be "utf-8"

Comment: Yes, I figured that and corrected it. But the problem persists :(

Comment: @alapalak sorry to hear that, try to google search how to solve special characters in python'